# Agregar todo un archivo csv a una lista

Tags: python, csv

¿Es posible agregar todo un archivo CSV a una lista?

Por ejemplo, mi archivo csv es:

```
peso,estatura,tiempo de entrenamiento,
15,162,3
169,192,4
```

¿Como puedo agregar todo eso a una lista?

Lo que quiero hacer es agregarlo a una lista, entonces si un usuario quiere cambiar algún dato del archivo, que el programa lo vuelva lista, el cambia el elemento en la lista y lo devuelva otra vez como archivo. No se si será posible, o si tienen recomendaciones para ello. Espero sus respuestas, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('Archivo.csv', 'r') as file:    
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')
    data = list(reader)

print(data)
```

Puedes abrir el archivo csv usando `with open('Archivo.csv', 'r') as file:`, donde `Archivo` es el nombre de tu archivo csv. Tienes que cambiar `Archivo` por el nombre que le hayas dado a tu archivo csv.

El resultado es:

```
[['peso', 'estatura', 'tiempo de entrenamiento', ''], ['15', '162', '3'], ['169', '192', '4']]
```

Comment: Para eso podrías hacer `data = list(reader)` y luego `print(data)`.